# Trying to convert String into a Double but getting NumberFormatException

Tags: java, numberformatexception

What I'm trying to do here is, I'm trying to read the numbers "1 2 3" from my text, `numbers.txt`. From there, I'm trying to set it into a string variable, three. From here, I'm trying to convert it into a double so that I can use the numbers to find the average of them. I keep getting this error:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 2 3"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:549)
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:512)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

I do apologize if this question has been asked in the past. I've looked into this error, as well as looking into anyone else who has asked similar questions on this website and still haven't found an answer.

Edit: I should've also added that, I have to find the average of 5 sets of numbers:

```
1 2 3 
5 12 14 6 4 0 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
17
2 90 80
```

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException , NumberFormatException {
        String three;
        File file = new File("numbers.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
        three = in.nextLine();
        double threeconversion = Double.parseDouble(three);
        System.out.println(three);



        }
    }
```

Comment: "1 2 3" is obviously not a valid double value. You want to read the line number by number (i.e. using something else instead of `nextLine()`), or split it into the individual numbers once you've read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of reading the entire line, you could let the `Scanner` do the heavy lifting for you by use `nextDouble()`:

```java
double sum = 0.0;
int count = 0;
while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
    double d = in.nextDouble();
    sum += d;
    count++;
}
double average = sum / count;
```

Comment: I should've also added that, there are five sets of numbers on the text. I have to find the average for each of the lines like so: 1 2 3 //
5 12 14 6 4 0 //
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 //
17 //
2 90 80

This was a great help but now i'm struggling to figure out how exactly i'm going to be able to go forward from this point.

Answer (score 1):

Take this example:
**1 2 3// 5 12 14 6 4 0 // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10// 17// 2 90 80**

If there is only a *space* in the string, it would be easy to just split and find the average. But your string has both *space* and *//*.

There are two approaches you could do for this.

1. Use *regex* to identify numbers in your string and added them to a *sum* variable and then find the average. You may need to use *StringBuilder* if there are any double digits in the final string. Refer regex here: [https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/10/regular-expression-example-in-java-to-check-String-number.html#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20check%20for,Pattern%20digitPattern%20%3D%20Pattern](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/10/regular-expression-example-in-java-to-check-String-number.html#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20check%20for,Pattern%20digitPattern%20%3D%20Pattern).
2. Use loops and arrays to split your string two times; store the result in another array or a list; find the average from that.

I've done the 2nd way. It's a little messy but simple to understand.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File file = new File("numbers.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);

        List<Double> container = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] temp1 = in.nextLine().split("//");
        for (String s1 : temp1) {
            String[] temp2 = s1.split(" ");
            for (String s2 : temp2) {
                try {
                    container.add(Double.parseDouble(s2));
                } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {}
            }
        }

        double sum = 0.0;
        for (double i : container) sum += i;
        System.out.printf("Average: %.2f\n", sum/container.size());
    }
```

*file* and *in* are already defined by you. *container* is an ArrayList to hold the final double numbers. Other variables *temp1, s1, temp2, s2* are temporary arrays and string to manipulate the original string.

First I split the *"//"* in your string. Then I split using *space*. Now, since your string is not properly formatted, there will be some random empty strings form into the temporary arrays when splitting. Hence there will be error when I parse them as double. That's why there is a *try-catch* in the code.

Comment: I feel really stupid for that and I do apologize if I wasted your time with this one. I did mean to space it out but I couldn't seem to figure out how to do so within edit. Each of those // means a different line of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You do:

```
three = in.nextLine();  // read the whole line from Scanner
double threeconversion = Double.parseDouble(three);  // parse this line to double (and have NFE when line contains more than one number)
```

You should do following:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
in.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);   // should be explicitly set to correctly work with decimal point
double sum = 0;
int total = 0;

while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
    total++;
    sum += in.nextDouble();
}

System.out.println("avg: " + (sum / total));
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the `NumberFormatException` because `1 2 3` is not a string representing a `double`; rather, it is a string which contains numbers.

You can read each line, split the values on whitespace, parse the values (obtained by splitting the line) into `double` and find their average.

**Using Stream API:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String three;
        File file = new File("numbers.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            double lineAvg = Arrays.stream(in.nextLine().split("\\s+"))
                                .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                                .average()
                                .getAsDouble();
            System.out.println(lineAvg);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2.0
6.833333333333333
5.5
17.0
57.333333333333336
```

**Without using Stream API:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String three;
        File file = new File("numbers.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            String[] arr = line.split("\\s+");
            double sum = 0;
            for (String s : arr) {
                sum += Double.parseDouble(s);
            }
            double lineAvg = sum / arr.length;
            System.out.println(lineAvg);
        }
    }
}
```